# Ensure my class stays positive

Tags: java, operators

I have a counter code which should have methods to add one and subtract one. I have to make sure the code never counts below 0. I am thinking  counter>= 0 plugs in somewhere. Or should it be in my driver file? Anyway here is the code. The first snippet is where I believe the "must stay positive" statement should be placed.

Should it be in this part?

```
public void minusOne(int count)
        {
            one -= count;
        }
```

The entire Code:

```
public class Counter 
{
    private int count; 
    private int one = 1;
    public Counter()
    {
            count = 0;
    }

        public void addOne(int count)
    {
        one += count;

    }

        public void minusOne(int count)
    {
        one -= count;
    }

        public void setCounter(int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }
        public int getCounter()
    {
        return count;
    }


}
```

Comment: Why are you changing the value of `one`?

Answer (score 0):

So if `one` goes negative, set it back to `zero`

```
    public void minusOne(int count)
    {
        one -= count;
        if (one < 0) 
          one = 0;
    }
```

Comment: If this answer was useful, please consider to accept and/or upvote

Comment: How do I accept an answer? apologies I am new to this community. Also while your answer works, I was thinking this might be better for this code.

Comment: if (count > 0){

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Counter {
    private int count;

    public Counter() {
        count = 0;
    }

    public void addOne() {
        count++; 
    }

    public void minusOne() {
        if(count > 0) {
            count--;
        }
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        if(count >= 0) {
            this.count = count;
        } else {
            this.count = 0;
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

1. First of your class only needs 1 field, count, to keep track of the count for this class.
2. The addOne method just needs to increment the count by 1 you don't need a field to hold 1.
3. in the minusOne method you need to check that the current count is >0 to decrement it by one.
4. the setCount method needs to make sure that the count that it is passed in is >= 0 otherwise we want to set that to be 0.

Comment: Okay got it, I was also thinking of altering the if statement so that it looks like if (count > 0){  count  -=  1; }.